# How to correctly pass files to asp.net mvc controller via jquery ajax request

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

So I am trying to pass 1 or multiple files to my .net mvc api controller. 
Everything was working great up until I wanted to add the files. Once I added the ability to try to send files no matter what I do I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

I've read through a lot of other forum posts and most of them just say to add `contentType: false` and `processData: false` to the ajax command. When I do that I get an error 415 back. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain what I am doing wrong with this.

Below is my model:

```
public class AuditStandardDto
{

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string StandardName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsInspect { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsAudit { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsReport { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsStandardReady { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsMaturityScore { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StandardStatusId { get; set; }

    public string StandardShortName { get; set; }

    public string StandardDescription { get; set; }

    public string AuthoritativeSource { get; set; }

    public string AuthoritativeURL { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StandardTypeId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> File { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/NewStandards/UpdateStandard/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult UpdateStandard(int id,AuditStandardDto standardDto)
    {
        try
        {
            var standardInDb = _dbContext.AuditStandards.Single(s => s.Id == id);

            standardInDb.StandardName = standardDto.StandardName;
            standardInDb.IsInspect = standardDto.IsInspect;
            standardInDb.IsAudit = standardDto.IsAudit;
            standardInDb.IsReport = standardDto.IsReport;
            standardInDb.IsMaturityScore = standardDto.IsMaturityScore;
            standardInDb.StandardStatusId = standardDto.StandardStatusId;
            standardInDb.StandardShortName = standardDto.StandardShortName;
            standardInDb.StandardDescription = standardDto.StandardDescription;
            standardInDb.AuthoritativeSource = standardDto.AuthoritativeSource;
            standardInDb.AuthoritativeURL = standardDto.AuthoritativeURL;
            standardInDb.StandardTypeId = standardDto.StandardTypeId;
            standardInDb.IsStandardReady = standardInDb.IsStandardReady;
            standardInDb.Updated = DateTime.Now;

            _dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return Ok();
        }
        catch 
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

and finally my jquery

```
$('#newStandard').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var standardTypeId = $('#ddlStandardType').val();
        var isInspect = $('#cbIsInspect').is(':checked');
        var isAudit = $('#cbIsAudit').is(':checked');
        var isReport = $('#cbIsReport').is(':checked');
        var isMaturityScore = $('#cbRequiresMaturityScore').is(':checked');
        var standardName = $('#txtStandardName').val();
        var standardShortName = $('#txtStandardShortName').val();
        var authoritativeSource = $('#txtAuthoritativeSource').val();
        var authoritativeUrl = $('#txtAuthoritativeURL').val();
        var standardStatusId = $('#ddlStandardStatus').val();
        var standardDescription = $('#txtStandardDescription').val();

        var vm = {
            "standardTypeId": standardTypeId,
            "isInspect": isInspect,
            "isAudit": isAudit,
            "isReport": isReport,
            "isMaturityScore": isMaturityScore,
            "standardName": standardName,
            "standardShortName": standardShortName,
            "authoritativeSource": authoritativeSource,
            "authoritativeURL": authoritativeUrl,
            "standardStatusId": standardStatusId,
            "standardDescription": standardDescription
        };

        $('#newStandard input[type=file]').each(function(index, file) {
            vm.file = file.files[0];
        });

        var url = '';
        if ($('#hfMode').val() === 'save') {
            url = '/api/newStandards/';
        } else {
            url = '/api/newStandards/UpdateStandard/' + $('#hfStandardId').val();
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: vm
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

you have keep one thing in mind, jQuery is a loosely typed script. This means you can send objects called JSON. I your C# method signature, you should use a generic type which is an Object type or even JSON. Once your C# Rest method receives the JSON Object, you could use a JSON parser like Newtonsoft and construct the wanted object from here.

You are getting an HTTP 415 error, because of type incompatibility which in turn means you are calling the wrong method.

TIP: If you want to send AJax based request to your server , then you must use JSON as a common denominator.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question as to how to send the file using a DTO like you should be able to do. I'd like to be able to send the file as part of my view model which would come over as JSON anyway's as that is how asp.net MVC does it mapping from my understanding.